# Adding rows to data frame in loop

Tags: python

I know this is a super basic question, but I'm stuck.

I am attempting to create a data frame. I want to create a data frame that contains the results of the for loop.

```
def nearest_neighbors(coordinates, wafer_map):
    for row in coordinates:
        map_tree = spatial.cKDTree(wafer_map)
        distance, index = map_tree.query(row)
        cols = ["Coordinates", "Distance to nearest coordinates", "Nearest coordinates"]
        num_list = [row, distance, wafer_map[index]]
        lst = []
        for a in range(len(coordinates)):
            lst.append(num_list)
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
        print(df1)

test = nearest_neighbors(coordinates, wafer_map)
print(test)
```

This produces a data frame with the correct amount of rows, but each row contains the same data.

Example of `num_list`: [array([ 45.96194078, -53.03300859]), 0.11039021695784783, array([ 45.96618342, -53.14331725])]

Edit:

Now it is producing an individual data frame for each row.. and the data is correct. How can I concatenate all these individual data frames into one data frame?

```
def nearest_neighbors2(coordinates, wafer_map):
    for row in coordinates:
        # construct a kd-tree
        map_tree = spatial.cKDTree(wafer_map)
        # find k nearest neighbors for each (x,y) coordinate
        distance, index = map_tree.query(row)
        cols = ["Coordinates", "Distance to nearest coordinates", "Nearest coordinates"]
        num_list = [row, distance, wafer_map[index]]
        d = defaultdict(list)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
        for a, b in zip(cols, num_list):
            d[a].append(b)
        df2 = df2.append(d, ignore_index=True)
        print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
def nearest_neighbors3(coordinates, wafer_map):
    list_of_dicts = []
    for row in coordinates:
        # construct a kd-tree
        map_tree = spatial.cKDTree(wafer_map)
        # find k nearest neighbors for each (x,y) coordinate
        distance, index = map_tree.query(row)
        cols = ["Coordinates", "Distance to nearest coordinates", "Nearest coordinates"]
        results = [row, distance, wafer_map[index]]
        results_dict = dict(zip(cols, results))
        list_of_dicts.append(results_dict)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
    return df

calculate_pt = nearest_neighbors(coordinates, wafer_map)
print(calculate_pt)
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner for loop, you are appending the same `num_list` for the entire for loop length. I think changing that part should do it. And for the `pd.DataFrame`, the data should not be a list, it should be in dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

Each row will contain the same data because you are appending same `num_list` in `lst` every time in the inner for loop.
Also, since your `df1` is inside outer for loop, you will only be able to store last iteration results in `df1`.